# SQL Server - Display only the most recent print statement in SSMS messages pane (while loop)

Tags: sql-server, loops, ssms, message

I have a script that usually takes several hours to run (mostly because it needs to be looped through a few hundred thousand times. Currently I have a print statement to check the progress so that each time it completes 1 iteration it prints out : "Query 1 of 100000 complete" then below that "Query 2 of 100000 complete" and so on and so forth.

Is there any way to delete old messages in SQL Server Management Studio so that the messages pane only displays the most recent print statement?

Answer (score 5):

You can't clear the print messages in `SSMS`. Print may not print immediately if you don't have `GO` statement in  your queries. **PRINT doesn’t necessarily output anything at the moment it’s called.**

You should not use print for tracking the progress of your query. To know more about this read [Stop Using PRINT to Track Query Progress](https://www.sqltheater.com/2017/09/12/stop-using-print/)

If you want to track the progress immediately, instead of print you can use `RAISEERROR` like following.

```
RAISERROR('SOME MESSAGE YOU WANT TO SHOW', 0, 1) WITH NOWAIT;
```

Ideally, you should have a log table, where you should be entering the progress for each step. This will give you the correct picture of what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using SSMS, you could use `sqlcmd` instead and store the output to a text file. For example, in powershell, you could run a command like:

```
sqlcmd -S YourServer -d YourDatabase -Q "EXEC YourStoredProcedure" > "C:\temp\sqlcmdsp.log"
```

Then, if you want to see where the process is at, you could simply open the txt if a non-locking application (like notepad or notepad++) and see where it's got to.